# Win7 could not support NVM hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, installation, operating-systems, nvm

I use win7 installation disk burned with ISO image and try to install new OS.
But get this error.Windows could not install on this disk.Windows need driver[standard NVM Express Controller].

Hard disk is Samsung 970 EVO Plus 250GB.
If I want to install win7, what should I do? Or else it's a dead road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 has no support for NVMe, so you have to create a custom installation media
that includes the driver.

Microsoft provides the
[Update to add native driver support in NVM Express in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-add-native-driver-support-in-nvm-express-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-03cd423b-d42e-66c2-722b-019d16455a6b),
but it is only for already-installed Windows 7 SP1.

A useful tool is the
[Windows 7 Image Updater](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/384921-Windows-7-Image-Updater-SkyLake-KabyLake-CoffeLake-Ryzen-Threadripper),
described as:

> **What does this tool do?**
>
> - Integrates updates till 2020
> - Integrates necessary drivers for modern PCs/laptops (USB3.0/3.1,NVMe,wi-fi, LAN and so on)
> - Integrates installer from Windows 10 (better support for NVMe drives)
> - Integrates post-setup script which installs NET Framework 4.8, VC Redistributables and WuaCpuFix ( https://github.com/p-lider/WuaCpuFix
>   )
>
> **Important notes:**
>
> - This tool won't work with custom images containing both x86 and x64 versions!
> - Make sure that you have more than 20 GiB of free space!
> - Whole updating process may take even few hours!
> - Yes .7z archive is huge because there are two windows 10 installers included (x86 and x64) and bunch of drivers!
> - CSM must be enabled in BIOS!

Read well the description of the tool, as well as the comments below.
The time to create the installation media is counted in hours.